# How to install JDK and Netbeans?

Tags: 10.10, installation, java, netbeans, jdk

I have downloaded a .bin file for JDK and am trying to install it. I have used these commands:

```
chmod +x jdk-6u23-linux-i586.bin
sudo ./jdk-6u23-linux-i586.bin
```

and got this output:

```
sudo: ./jdk-6u23-linux-i586.bin: command not found
```

Comment: thinking there's a typo in your command or a permissions error.  it works for me with similar commands.  it could also be some sudo weirdness.  I ALWAYS use a rootshell instead of sudo.

Comment: That error can also be shown when you try to execute a 32bits binary on a 64 bits system.

Comment: @aking1012, `sudo -s` do the same thing.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - thanks for the heads up.  good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help, but I solved my own problem.

When I installed Ubuntu and I installed OpenJDK. I was trying to install the Sun JDK, which led to the error.

I resolved the problem by uninstalling OpenJDK, restarting the machine, and then extracting the file mentioned above. It was successfully extracted and NetBeans easily found the JDK path.

Now I'm enjoying Java Development with NetBeans.

Answer (score 8):

To install Netbeans, you can simply install the [netbeans](http://packages.ubuntu.com/netbeans) package. This will install everything Netbeans needs, including Java.

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

To install Java, but without installing Netbeans

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

If you want the proprietary version of Java, you need to:

- [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)

To install these packages, use the Software Centre, which is available from the Applications menu.

Comment: i have solved my problem before reading your answers.

Comment: @user8900 - Please answer your own question outlining the steps you took to solve it. After 2 days, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: dear i m not understanding what your are saying?..so can you voice chat with me? at skype  . i am available at skype.

Comment: thnx for guidence.i got your instruction and follow them.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans is available from the Ubuntu software Center, you should install from there unless you have a strong reason to use a different version.

Comment: I have solved my problem before read your answers. Special Thanks to everybody have give me suggestions. so I have solved my problem in simple way. when i install ubuntu and i have already install OPEN JDK.i was trying to install sun jdk its giving me error. so after all , i uninstall Open jdk and restart machine and then extract file i have mention above .its successfully extracted and Netbean easly found jdk path. Now i m enjoying Java Development with Netbean.

Comment: One should be aware though that the ubuntu software centre version is the plain JavaSE version.

Answer (score 1):

In future use these 2 scripts I wrote :D...

Java before Netbeans...

```
#!/bin/sh

#Delete the line below if you only want the "open" JDK & JRE
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre;

#Makes the /usr/lib/jvm in case...
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm

#Clean out /tmp...
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
cd /tmp

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-i586.tar.gz;
tar -xvf ./*gz;

#Move it to where it can be found...
sudo mv /tmp/jdk1.7.* /usr/lib/jvm/;

#Add the new Java to the bin 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/bin/java 3;

#User chooses
sudo update-alternatives --config java;

exit 0;
```

Netbeans...

```
# @author Yucca Nel
# Update as needed for newer Netbeans releases :D

#!/bin/sh

#Clean out /tmp...
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*;
cd /tmp;

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of Netbeans or replace 'javase with 'javaee' or add jee manually via
#Netbeans 'plugins as needed.
wget http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/7.0.1/final/bundles/netbeans-7.0.1-ml-javase-linux.sh;
sh /tmp/*sh;

#Add Netbeans launcher to your PATH. Doing so allows you to run 'netbeans' command from the terminal
sudo ln -s ~/netbeans-7.0.1/bin/netbeans /usr/local/bin/;

exit 0;
```