# How do I install Java?

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk

How do I install Java, including in my browser, so websites with Java work?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

There are several implementations of Java. The three most common implementations when talking about it for Ubuntu are:

- **OpenJDK**: The primary goal of the OpenJDK project is to produce an
  open-source implementation of the [Java SE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) Platform (6 and 7). This is
  the default version of Java that Ubuntu uses and is the easiest to
  install.
- **Sun Java**: Sun Java is the reference implementation for Java 6. Its support [has been discontinued](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64515/will-suns-java-be-available-from-canonicals-partner-repository/88035#88035) in Ubuntu.
- **Oracle Java**: Oracle Java is the OpenJDK Java Se Platform version 7 implementation from Oracle. Oracle introduced with this implementation [a license](http://java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml#eula) that prevents distribution.

Since Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) and [due to license issues](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/JavaTeam) Ubuntu will no longer distribute Oracle's JDK and [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment). Also, previous versions supplied on PPAs suffer from security issues and are not recommended to be installed on any Ubuntu system.

There are no more supported .deb [releases from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) with reference to Sun Java or Oracle Java, Ubuntu officially supports OpenJDK and OpenJRE implementation of Java which is the base for Oracle's own implementation.

OpenJRE is the official implementation of Java Runtime Environment (JRE) for your Ubuntu systems and should suffice to run any Java program that you might require and it's included in the main repository and it's easily installable.

#### OpenJRE

By opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

this installs `openjdk-11-jre` (at the time of writing this, you may install a newer java version in the future, which is now, if it installs a different openjdk version I guess)

The `openjdk-11-jre` package contains just the Java Runtime Environment. If you want to develop Java programs then install the `default-jdk` package:

---

Also important is to install the wrapper for supporting Java applications on your web browser, the *Iced-Tea Java Plugin*.

#### IcedTea Plugin

[image: Install via the software center]

Or via a terminal

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

Or look for `icedtea-plugin` in the Ubuntu Software Center.

---

To make sure that you are running the correct version of Java, use this command to set your choice:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

`java -version` should display the choice you previously made.

---

**If you need to install OpenJDK-JRE 6 or OpenJDK-JDK 6**

[`openjdk-6-jre`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jre) (click to install) is available for installation for [Ubuntu 8.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_8.04_LTS_.28Hardy_Heron.29) (Hardy Heron) and up.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
```

Or if you need the developers' package, [`openjdk-6-jdk`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openjdk-6-jdk) (click to install), install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

A version of the [`icedtea-plugin`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icedtea6-plugin) (click to install) is also available to install if you are going to use OpenJDK 6.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

---

**If you really want to use Oracle's Java SE Platform**, see *[How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/56104/176889)*.

Comment: Under 15.04 the icedtea-7-plugin does not work well with Firefox.  I've found that downloading a tar.gz distribution and manually symlinking libnpjp2.so  into /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins made it work.  Note that the websites need to be marked as trusted too in the java control panel (this in turn is only possible if you do not have spaces in the full folder name of the unpacked jre).

Comment: OpenJDK is now openjdk-8-jre

Comment: on Ubuntu 16, Firefox 50, with Open-JDK 8... doing apt-get install icedtea-netx followed by apt-get install icedtea-plugin did the trick for me!  Thank you for your answer, super helpful!  :)

Comment: Always install the latest version of Open JDK by using `sudo apt install default-jdk`. Currently this installs version 8.

Answer (score 52):

Installing OpenJDK is not enough for enabling Java in browsers. You'll also need to install the [`icedtea-7-plugin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/icedtea-7-plugin) package:

[image: Install via the software center]

A restart of the browser might be required.

Comment: How is this up to date in 2018?

Comment: @KonradGajewski Not sure, I have recently not used any Java applets. In fact, Firefox 52 has [dropped](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins) support for Java plugins and so did [Chrome 45](https://www.java.com/chrome).

Comment: For the past few hours, I was unable to get it running under Firefox, Chromium, or Chrome. I got Java working in Konqueror.

Answer (score 22):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

For installing Oracle Java 7:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins #just in case, this will be added to the package in the next version
sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
```

- [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/)

Comment: After the installation finishes, if you wish to see if it was successful, you can run the following command:

`java -version` (see http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html )

Answer (score 17):

**Installing OpenJDK - Recommended**

The simplest way to install Java on Ubuntu is to use **OpenJDK**. This will work fine for most people. To install it, click on the small button with the Ubuntu logo on it, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

After opening the Dash Home, you need to type in **Terminal**. Click on the icon that is circled in the screenshot below.

[image]

This will open the **Terminal**, which is Ubuntu's version the the Windows Command prompt, though the Terminal has many more features. Now, copy and paste the following command into the Terminal window. You will need to use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste text into the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

You will need to enter your password to use this command. Although it will not show up in the Terminal, it will still be entered when you type it. After running this command, you will be set up to run and develop Java applications.

**Installing Oracle Java**

OpenJDK works fine for most people, but if you play Minecraft, you will want to use Oracle Java instead. To install Oracle Java, run the command below one at a time in the Terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

This will download Java from Oracle's website, and install it for you.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: -1 for 3 major reasons: 1 - JDK and JRE alone are not enough to enable java in Web Browsers. You still need `icedtea-plugin` package (`icedtea6-plugin` or `icedtea7-plugin`, the one that matches your java); 2 - JDK already includes the JRE, so no need to install both. Choose either JRE for regular users (like the OP) or JDK for java developers. 3 - Since you had the trouble to post nice screenshots, why suggest the terminal route? Software Center is much more friendly and recommended in this case

Comment: webupd8team's PPA has been discontinued. [Reference](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)

Comment: WARNING: The ppa webupd8team has been DISCONTINUED. Read why here: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Answer (score 12):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

Open your terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and:

Now this will install the [latest Java version](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/oracle-java-7-update-40-7u40-released.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... but i tried the last sentence "sudo update-alternatives --config java" says "There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java Nothing to configure." How this is supposed to check if it is in use ???

Comment: @Septrba You have only "one" Java version installed, only one can be in use, and it's the one you have installed. If you had more than one installed, it would list and show which one is in use. Probably shouldn't have added that to my answer, since it was probably more confusing than helpful. :P

Answer (score 10):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

Oracle Java 8 was just released (stable). To install it in Ubuntu, you can use the WebUpd8 Java PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

The PPA itself doesn't provide Oracle Java 8 binaries (that's not allowed by the Oracle Java license). Instead, an installer is used that automatically downloads and installs Oracle Java 8. Using this PPA, you'll also receive automatic Java 8 updates.

More information and some tips on using / further configuring Oracle Java 8 @ WebUpd8 is in *[Install Oracle Java 8 In Ubuntu Via PPA Repository [JDK 8]](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)*.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, because of issues with its license, Oracle Java is no longer distributed within the official Ubuntu repositories. You have two main options: either try OpenJDK -- an open source replacement for Oracle Java -- or proceed with the "manual" installation (which is exactly what you were trying to do). Both these options are described on the help wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java. This page also include some other alternatives that, depending on your needs, you may find more suitable.

*Just a side note: most of the time, with Ubuntu, you should not download software from the Internet, but rather use the Ubuntu Software Center. The software you'll find there is ensured to be stable, safe and to respect the standard conventions of the system. Oracle Java is just an exception to this rule.*

Answer (score 4):

Just go to Aplications --> Ubuntu software center and then search for `Java`.
[image]

Comment: Your answer would be that the OP installs the previous Java Runtime Environment, and not the latest version jre-6u25-linux-i586.bin

Comment: Scouser73, jre-6u25-linux-i586.bin sounds like the proprietary Java implementation from Oracle. This question is about OpenJDK.

Comment: The one that is marked (in orange) is the open-jdk java6 runtime!

Comment: scouser73 is referring to a security update of Oracle Java. I don't know if the current version if affected, the installed JRE version is 6b22 but bear in mind that this is **unrelated** to the version number of Oracle Java, see https://dbhole.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/why-do-xx-and-yy-in-jdk6-uxx-and-openjdk-byy-differ/

Comment: well, Scouser73 had problems with a we page. I only use the jdk and that is all I ever need so I thought it would help.

Answer (score 3):

# current java release - get both [jdk / jre  download here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/java

cd /usr/local/java
```

# remove previous installs if any

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/java/jdk*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/java/jre*
```

# move downloaded/expanded dirs into /usr/local/java

```
sudo mv ~/jdk* /usr/local/java/
sudo mv ~/jre* /usr/local/java/

cd /usr/local/java/
```

# create symbolic links

```
sudo ln -s jdk*  jdk
sudo ln -s jre*  jre
```

# ONLY need to do below on fresh ubuntu install - IGNORE if previously installed any java version as its already in place

# setup symlinks :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jre/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jre/bin/javaws
```

Finally, put these in your ~/.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

now you're locked and loaded ;-)

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Since Ubuntu 16.04 you can install this without the ppa via

```
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

LEGACY ANSWER:

For Ubuntu < 16.04 there was no official package for Java 8 from [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) ( the open source version ), but you can install it via [this](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA by running:

```
$> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
$> sudo apt-get update
$> sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: I just ran the last two commands without the first and it works. So it looks like there's an official package now (2016).

Comment: Updated the answer for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to install Java in Ubuntu:

Install OpenJDK (The open source equivalent to Sun's Java) directly from Ubuntu Software Center. All you need to do is search for Java. That tends to work as is for me.

If you need Sun's Java, say if you want to play Minecraft, you download the JRE as you described from Java.com, but make sure your .bin-file can be executed. You do that by opening a terminal and typing the following (I will assume you have it in your Downloads folder so change the cd line accordingly if that's not where it is):

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
sudo chmod +x jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
```

Then, you should be able to close your terminal, right click on your .bin-file and select "Execute", which should run the installer. If this is not an option, just do the following from terminal (in the same folder as the two other actions):

```
./jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin
```

That simply runs the specified file and if you successfully typed in the two first lines, the installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing Java in Firefox, then

```
plug=~/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so && 
test -e $plug && readlink -f $plug || 
  ln -f -s `find ~ -wholename '*jdk*lib*libnpjp2.so' -or -wholename '*jre*lib*libnpjp2.so' | head -n 1` `dirname $plug` && 
ls -la $plug
```

This script will overwrite libnpjp2.so even if it exists, but points to wrong file (for example, the symlink is broken).

Comment: Where should this script be run from (directory location)?

Comment: from wherever you want, find looks for plugin in `~` and usbdirectories. $plug variable makessure that symlink is put in right directory.

Answer (score 0):

I made a text-based Java installer using terminal commands. It uses `wget`, `tar`, `update-alternatives`, and `ln`. It will install the Oracle JRE with the Firefox plugin.

You can download the installer from [Google Drive here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ETea13k-9ydnhtSndDNUhWUlE/edit?usp=sharing). Then put it in your home folder, open Terminal and type `bash Install`. Then it will run the installer in Terminal. It uses `sudo`, so you will need to type your password after it downloads. Also, this is the 64-bit version, so I will add the 32 bit later.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

Detailed instructions to install Oracle Java 8 are updated in the blog [here](https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/06/22/installing-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-18-04/).

You can also use below commands for a quick answer -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default

javac -version
```

Please do note that you can also install openJDK which is also maintained by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `sudo apt xxx` others are not doing some miricle.

To install the latest version of `JDK ( Java Development Kit )` Follow the steps.

1. Go to Openjdk website https://jdk.java.net/
2. Download the `tar` file of latest version right now its 18.
3. Extract it
4. Copy it somewhere like `/opt` directory using `mv`
5. Add the path of the `bin` folder to the `PATH`, by adding this to your `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:absolute_Path_of_bin_folder >> ~/.bashrc
```

and there you have it.