# How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?

Tags: package-management

I can't update my system because it freezes while installing a third-party update (zramswap-enabler)!

Sometimes I get the following message in Update manager:

> Could not initialize the package information An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
>
> Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
>
> `E:The package zramswap-enabler needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

I tried to remove the zramswap-enabler, but it's impossible because I get the following message:

```
dpkg: error processing zramswap-enabler (--remove):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zramswap-enabler
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Actually I would really reinstall that package, but it is unable to do it! If I remove this third-party PPA then the system is warning me about a very very serious problem.

So why can I not install/reinstall/remove/update this package and why freezes the updater if I try to update?

Comment: Related: [Fix half-installed package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490671/fix-half-installed-package), [Apt/Synaptic needs to reinstall package but can't find the archive for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it)

Answer (score 159):

[*Edited out of the question and added as an answer.*](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/148715/4)

1. Make sure that your PPA is set up.
2. Remove the broken package via the following command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq zramswap-enabler
   ```
3. Install the package again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install zramswap-enabler
   ```
4. After restart (not necessary), you are able to install the updates correctly!

Actually you can fix any "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state” issues with this solution!

Comment: @CharlesL Not a problem! Note that this answer is community wiki, and the solution was initially found by the author of the question, so I can't take credit for it. All I did was edit and reorganize to move it into an answer.

Comment: I had some trouble with this one (14.04 to 16.04).  "gcc-doc" didn't work. The error message showed `/var/cache/apt/archives/gcc-doc_4%3a5.3.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`, and the tools reject '%' in the name, so the full name didn't work either. I ended up removing files until it was happy -- see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321414&page=2 .

Comment: I had to use a combination of `--force-remove-reinstreq` and `--purge --force-depends` when `cpp-5` somehow had broken dependency problems.

Comment: This didn't work for me, add `autoremove` and `autoclean` from Hamman's answer!

Comment: @Luka this post is a few years old now and is community wiki meaning that you should be able to edit it directly (the rep requirement is far lower)

Answer (score 102):

This worked for me after pretty much scouring the whole of AskUbuntu and Ubuntu forums! ([Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5216367#post5216367)). I'm running Lubuntu 14.04

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>
sudo apt-get remove <packagename>
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Finally! This did the trick when dpkg and apt won't remove or reinstall a package

Comment: Thanks. This saved me BIG TIME! I tried skipping the last line, followed by a `apt-get install...` and had to start over and do ALL four lines, then I could finally purge my package. :)

Comment: The only true answer which works any time.

Comment: This helped when I had problems with gcc-doc and cpp-doc after an upgrade from 14.04. I had more recent tools install from ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test and they screwed everything up. Moral of the story, purge ppas before upgrading to a new release. But this tip helped me in fixing the mess afterwards.

Comment: I have done the following but got an error:
`sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1:i386.*  /tmp/`

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libgcc1:i386`

dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libgcc1:i386:
 libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc1:i386 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcc1:i386

Comment: This worked for me.  I removed 1 file to correct my cacti removal issue.  Removed /var/lib/dpkg/info/cacti.list

Comment: Worked for me too! Thank you!

Comment: This worked - `autoremove` and `autoclean` were important!

Comment: @GopakumarNG I added `--force-depends` to the dkpg command and it worked. Also worth noting that my apt-get autoremove did not work because the pacakge was not installed, so I installed the package and ran autoremove and autoclean and everything worked.

Comment: Warning for copy-pasters, like me, because of the `*`: `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.* /tmp/` isn't undone by switching the paths like so: `sudo mv /tmp/ /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.*` I should have known.

Answer (score 25):

I had a situation worse than this. I had to remove the half-installed packages by forcing dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends <package-name>
```

Then I had to reinstall them

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That should solve any issue. But please make sure you have network connectivity when you try to do this. Otherwise, you will have to go through even more trouble.

Comment: I get an error: **dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf**

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are correct to mention a package removal followed by `apt-get install -f` to reinstall the broken package (and fully install other half-installed packages). However, this can be done in one step:

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall zramswap-enabler
```

Answer (score 3):

i'd try cleaning the status of my installation before resorting to uninstalling whatever created the problem:

```
apt-get autoclean
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install -f
```

much better way to solve this in most cases and in at least one instance had helped me when the other way wouldn't work (because **huge** dependencies on the package to be removed)

Comment: This yields an error: `sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: Permission denied`

Comment: I'd guess you did this from an non-admin account. Try prefixing each line with sudo or completely login as root (i.e. with: "sudo su" and your password or "su" and the admin-password)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with quagga, the routing daemon. Just reinstaling the package worked for me:

```
# apt-get install -f  
<some output ommited>
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal.

wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/q/quagga/quagga_0.99.22.4-1+wheezy3_i386.deb
dpkg -i quagga_0.99.22.4-1+wheezy3_i386.deb
```

Now its ok again:

```
#apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me when I got disconnected from the internet while downloading the `wireshark` package. After that, when I tried to reinstall it, it threw the same error:

```
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state
```

I've tried all the commands to install, purge, remove and reinstall but nothing worked.

After a little bit of googling, I stumbled upon this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libwireshark8_2.2.6+g32dac6a-2ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb
```

(changed `libwireshark8_2.2.6+g32dac6a-2ubuntu0.16.04_amd64.deb` with the package that was creating the problem in the directory `/var/cache/apt/archives/`).

After running this command all the issues were resolved. I removed the package again using:

```
sudo apt --purge remove libwireshark8:amd64
sudo apt autoremove to fully remove the package.
```

Then I installed `wireshark` again using:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

Everything works smoothly now!

References:

- [How To Solve ”Sub process usr bin dpkg returned an error code 1″ Error?](https://www.poftut.com/solve-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1-error/)
- [Fix dpkg error](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html)

Answer (score -1):

I used this to fix this same issue:

```
apt reinstall [package]
```