# Cannot update system - stuck on zramswap-enabler

Tags: updates, dpkg, partial-upgrade, zram

I'm having the same problem as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state) on two computers (one runs 12.04, while the other runs 11.10), but the solution provided does not work for me.

When I do update and upgrade through the terminal, I get the following

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package zramswap-enabler.
(Reading database ... 216245 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace zramswap-enabler 0.2.1-0~19~precise1 (using .../zramswap-enabler_0.2.1-0~21~precise1_all.deb) ...
```

and then it simply stays like that.

When I try to update using the Update Manager, I get a warning that not updates can be insalled and I need to do a partial upgrade. Again, when I try to do the partial upgrade, the proces is simply stuck at the zramswap-enabler update.

When I try to do as the solution mentioned above said, I get this:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq zramswap-enabler
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 216244 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing zramswap-enabler ...
```

and just like when I try to update, it simply stays stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the process stalls at "Preparing to replace zramswap-enabler", open another terminal and try running "sudo start zramswap".

Comment: Worked like a charm for the pc running 12.04. I'll try on the other one later. thanks for the help.

Comment: Worked on 11.10 as well.