# How to fix rpm-common package is in very bad inconsistent state?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, rpm

The Software Updater prompted me that there were updates available for install.  After installing, however, I keep receiving crash report prompts, especially after rebooting.  My system appears to be running okay besides the receiving the crash reports.

The crash reports state:

```
package rpm-common 4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1 failed to install/upgrade: 
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; 
you should  reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

I'm not sure how to remove this package and attempt a reinstall.  I'm afraid I may make things worse.

I just made the switch to Ubuntu, so I am very much a beginner.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling then reinstalling the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove rpm-common
sudo apt-get install rpm-common
```

If the removal of the package gives you problems, try following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error).

You will likely be forced to remove some more, dependent packages, in the first step. Please take note of them, and reinstall them after you've successfully reinstalled *rpm-common*.

Answer (score 1):

The [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error) provided by @AndersOlsson above held the answer to my problems.

The commands I ran to fix my issue were:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/rpm-common.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq rpm-common
sudo apt-get remove rpm-common
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After running these commands, I was able to re-install the package with no issues.