# Emacs24 unmet dependencies problem

Tags: dependencies, emacs

I'm unable to use `apt-get` due to unmet dependencies in emacs24. I'm not sure what happened, but I'm unable to apt anything.

Here is the output:

```
user5@system:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
emacs24 : Depends: emacs24-bin-common (= 24.5+1-6ubuntu1) but 24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

- Can't remove emacs24!
- Can't reinstall emacs24
- Can't `apt-get install -f`

All result in "unmet dependencies errors" for emacs 24.

The issue seems to be that [emacs24 depends on 24.5+1-6ubuntu1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25642396/) and [my system insists on installing 24.5+1-6ubuntu1.1](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25642427/)

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The good people on the #ubuntu Freenode IRC channel helped a LOT. Here is what we found:

1. Need to follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error) to get apt to a steady state.
2. Install Emacs25 using [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/install-emacs-25-ppa-ubuntu-16-04-14-04/).

Took about 2 hours to debug! Wish I could share all the pastebin.ubuntu links, but my rep is too light!