# Can't properly update or upgrade, error processing package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

Every time I try any "apt update" or "upgrade" or anything similar I get the error

```
dpkg: error processing package libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
```

I don't really know what to do anymore, I tried all "configure" and "reconfigure" and "autoclean" commands and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried with the --fix-missing parameter?

Comment: yes, and I get the same error ;-;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the problem by following the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error) just changing the to the proper package.
As it's a different problem I will leave this post here so anyone with the same problem as me can find the solution easy.