# DPKG Unconfigured errors

Tags: dpkg

```
ernel-common-390 amd64 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [12.2 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-dkms-390 amd64 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [28.1 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-compute-utils-390 amd64 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [70.3 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-utils-390 amd64 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [327 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 amd64 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [1,616 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 nvidia-driver-390 amd64 390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 [394 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 nvidia-prime all 0.8.8.2 [8,412 B]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 pkg-config amd64 0.29.1-0ubuntu2 [45.0 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 screen-resolution-extra all 0.17.3 [11.7 kB]
Fetched 85.5 MB in 11s (7,717 kB/s)                                            
dpkg: error processing package libidn11:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 systemd depends on libidn11 (>= 1.13); however:
  Package libidn11:amd64 is not configured yet.
```

Dont know why it does this. This is after trying to install nvidia drivers. When I try to reinstall what it tells me to, it says dpkg is in use. Also couldn't fix that as well, not even by deleting keys. I've went through the rabbit hole and I have hit a roadblock. I need to be able to install Nvidia drivers to play Steam games or else they don't work. I also can't install other certain packages. If there's a way to get the pre installed Ubuntu graphics drivers to work with Steam Play games on Steam, then please tell me. That could help me divert from this issue, since it forces me to use the Ubuntu preinstalled graphics driver/metapackage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error)

Comment: It gave me another error similar to this one when I tried what that answer states. I have no access to my computer currently and I want to go to sleep since I have been on the computer trying to fix this since forever so I might not be able to respond to any further comments or answers.

Comment: It would help if I could get the preinstalled Ubuntu drivers to work with my Nvidia card to take advantage of it's full power and compatibility with new games, since the Nvidia drivers I installed before this happened fixed my gaming issues on Steam Play. If I could make the current Ubuntu drivers work on Steam play then I wouldn't need to fix this issue.