# sudo apt-get install error code 01

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg

Sudo apt-get install (update, upgrade etc) have all stopped working on my system.  I followed come advice threads online, and seem to have made things worse!

Currently, 
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

returns the message:

```
dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-properties-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

While

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common
```

returns the message:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: old software-properties-common package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-common_0.97.11_all.deb (--unpack):
 new software-properties-common package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
```

Any ideas?

@Raffa:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pythin3-minimal
```

returns the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 software-properties-common
 gnome-menus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Something new: 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade`

tells me:
`Package python3 is not configured yet.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error)

Comment: It seems that `python3` is not in good shape. Reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal` then run `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`.

Comment: Please try option#1 and if not successful try option#2 in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501

Comment: @Raffa:  Assuming option 01 to be ````sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq python````, this also fails.  Trying option 2 now.  EDIT:  option 2 also fails.

Comment: No, I mean option#1 and option#2 in this link here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501

Comment: My apologies.  I have tried option 01:  to tells me python3 is not configured.  Trying option 2 now.

Comment: @Raffa:  I can confirm neither option 1 nor option 2 worked.

Comment: Then unfortunately your system might be broken beyond repair due to broken `python3` which is extremely essential for system operations. Your only option is to boot from a live USB then bind your system directories to the live system and try reinstalling `python3` from there.

Comment: Oh.  Yay!  Is it time to reinstall form scratch then?

Comment: @Raffa:  For information, It seems I have fixed things!  I have posted below how I did it, and will be back tomorrow to accept my answer.  Thanks for your help though, you gave me the leads I needed to be able to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: This is good news. Well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following leads picked up from @Raffa (Thanks Raffa!), I managed to get things working after doing the following:

First, manually reinstall Python:

```
apt-get download python3 python3.7 python3.7-minimal libpython3.7-minimal
sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Then manually reinstall software-properties-common:

```
apt-get download software-properties-common
sudo dpkg -i *software-properties-common*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

I think that was just to reset my system to where it was when I started.  I got the fix from the Reddit thread:  https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/aduzbg/upgrading_1804_to_1810_python3_install_is/

```
apt-get remove --purge python2.7-minimal
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that, things worked again!