# Can't find a way to remove nrf-udev package

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dpkg, udev

Edit:
[second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510887/666471) fixed my problem

The suggested [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error) doesn't fix my problem, as shown below I tried to do that exact same thing without success (output shown below)

I have installed "nrf-udev" package (following [this guide](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fug_nrfutils%2FUG%2Fnrfutils%2Fnrfutil_install_linux_dependencies.html))  some time ago and now I can't remove and now it's blocking me from upgrading other packages due to errors it's causing.

For example I try:

```
sudo dpkg --remove nrf-udev
```

and I get the following:

```
dpkg: error processing package nrf-udev (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nrf-udev
```

When I try to install it to fix this:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i nrf-udev_1.0.1-all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package nrf-udev.
(Reading database ... 891111 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack nrf-udev_1.0.1-all.deb ...
Unpacking nrf-udev (1.0.1) over (1.0.1) ...
Reloading udev rules...
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: warning: old nrf-udev package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Reloading udev rules...
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive nrf-udev_1.0.1-all.deb (--install):
 new nrf-udev package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Reloading udev rules...
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 new nrf-udev package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nrf-udev_1.0.1-all.deb
```

Following suggestions in the output:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-udevd.service
Failed to parse bus message: No such device or address
$ journalctl -xe
Journal file /var/log/journal/4ed21a70afb14542b7a7237653af2121/user-1000@9377c5d7ee0c41929c6d3230e7fe0fef-00000000005d1def-000614d5d95a6897.journal uses an unsupported feature, ignoring file.
-- No entries --
```

Trying to force remove it with dpkg:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq nrf-udev
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
(Reading database ... 891108 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nrf-udev (1.0.1) ...
Reloading udev rules...
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nrf-udev (--remove):
 installed nrf-udev package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nrf-udev
```

Now even when I try to upgrade packages I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -y 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package nrf-udev needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

This is on ubuntu20