# How to get icedtea7-plugin?

Tags: 11.10, java, openjdk

On Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), I installed openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk but could not find **icedtea7-plugin**. 
How to get the plugin?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_147-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.0) (7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Apparently, the plugin is not yet available ([and it’s a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/905714)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install icedtea-web` is the correct command.

Comment: I tried the command and was told that I have installed the latest version.

But:

$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for -javaplugin.so.
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so

I could not find in the Ubuntu repositories icedtea7-plugin package, only the icedtea6-plugin.

Comment: If you open `firefox` and type `about:plugins` on the address bar icedtea is not listed as the java plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is listed. Visually it seems that the java plugin running but in version 6. I wish use the version icedtea7. In the Oracle Web site test says I have java 6.23. What to do?

Comment: I only have openjdk7 installed and the oracle site tells me the same, I would say do not worry about it.

Comment: your java -version tells your that you are using the version you want, icedtea is running fine, only oracle is reporting it wrong I would say.

Comment: Thanks. In another test the same information appeared in the browser. I just hope that the browser is actually using the correct version of openjdk7. I think it is helpful to better performance and access to Internet banking.

Comment: I have only openjdk7 installed and when trying to install icedtea-plugin, apt is installing the whole openjdk-6-jre. So that’s unfortunately not the solution!

Comment: ``sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin``

Comment: This command has changed over time, however One Zero's answer will always install correctly, and is a more visual method, which I think is best for the audience of this site.

Comment: You know, it would have taken you less time to fix this answer than the time it took to comment and down-vote.

Comment: @Greq There, fixed. No more issues with the command for a very long time. Also *I do not like it because it is command line and this site values more graphical answers* is simply bs. [No offense](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/60/should-answers-have-terminal-or-gui-instructions).

Answer (score 5):

Install `icedtea6-plugin`

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

[For more help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java/48472#48472)

[image]

[image]

its 6 with java 7

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

Comment: This solves my problem. It was similar to topic starter's one, but I was to switch java alternatives and it had failed because of missing alternative for that icedtea plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Till the OpenJDK-7 IcedTea plugin gets released, you can use the following workaround:

http://r-interface.blogspot.in/2012/05/java-openjdk-install-errors-in-ubuntu.html