# Completely uninstall and reinstall OpenJDK

Tags: uninstall, openjdk

I searched askubuntu and tried the suggestions but failed .I try this question:[How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-reinstall-java)

***1.I run `sudo apt-cache search openjdk` get the following:***

`openjdk-6-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-6-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-6-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-6-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-6-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-6-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-6-jre-lib - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
openjdk-6-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
openjdk-6-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
openjdk-7-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-7-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-7-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-7-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-7-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-7-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-7-jre-lib - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
openjdk-7-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
openjdk-7-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files`

**2.run sudo apt-get remove openjdk get the following:**
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jdk is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 182 not upgraded.`

Comment: get the answer:    `sudo dpkg --list; sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk` thanks @izx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot remove OpenJDK 7 because **it is not installed**. If you are trying to remove OpenJDK 6, try `sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jdk`, or `sudo apt-get remove default-jdk`.

`apt-cache search` only shows you available packages, not the packages you have installed. For that, try `sudo dpkg --list`; `sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk` will show you any JDK-related packages installed on your system.

Comment: How can i search the packages i installed?What is the difference between packages available and packages installed?

Comment: I try both commend you post,get the same results:    `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package default-jdk is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 182 not upgraded.`

Comment: Please update question with output of `sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk`. Available means "CAN BE installed after downloading" while installed means "IS installed on your system"

Comment: thanks @izx i successed remove openjdk.How can i close the question.

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer if it helped -- this will also close the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Run this command, which lets you choose which Java installation to make the default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

---

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java         1         manual mode
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I tried to reinstall Java completely. This may help you to remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk*
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then, if you want, install Java:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Following these steps helped me to solve my  problem.