# How to completely remove other versions of Java on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, server, apt, java, dpkg

I have been trying to install Java on my *dedicated server*. I have partially installed multiple versions of Java and now cannot un-install them as they all have dependencies.

Whenever I try and un-install I get:

```
Errors were encountered whilst processing:
openjdk-6-jre-headless
openjdk-6-jre
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*Re-install can't be done unless I contact my host and pay 15$.*

Comment: Please provide also the apt error itself, not only the summary that it failed.

Comment: How/where would i get/find this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try uninstalling it following the steps given here: https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/83046.

And then you can install it again using the steps given here: [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java).

*I'm not providing the answers because they are long and are better off at their own pages*.