# Oracle java giving me trouble with strange warning. Details Below

Tags: java

Heres the error:warning: current package is oracle-java8, but binary format already installed by openjdk-7. i used the purge command on openjdk before i tried to  install Oracle Java 8 . now I'm at a loss.

Comment: **What** command is giving you that error?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I used the instructions from [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335457/how-to-uninstall-openjdk) to remove OpenJdk... or at least i thought i did.  to install i used [Link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)to install Java 8 via PPA.

Comment: So you used `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes.

Comment: And how are you installing Oracle Java 8?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Webupd8.org PPA

Comment: I suggest you reinstall openjdk, then install Java 8, then run `update-java-alternatives` to select Java8, then (optionally) try to remove openjdk. The cost of keeping the previous version (in disk space) is pretty low (because modern disks just keep getting bigger).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Okay, I'll try that now.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's giving me no root privileges error.

Comment: [sudo make me a sandwich](http://xkcd.com/149/)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If it gives me no readout on the results, that means it worked right?

Comment: What is the result of `sudo update-java-alternatives -l`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386
java-8-oracle 1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle oi this mini-markdown formatting jazz is confusing...

Comment: Congrats! Java 8 **is** installed. `sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle` and then `java -version`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Huzzah! Thanks sooooo much. If it's not too much to ask, could you compile the instructions you gave me into an answer, I want to mark it as such, so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, reinstall openjdk. Then install Java 8. Then run `update-java-alternatives` to select Java8. Finally, (optionally) try to remove openjdk. The cost of keeping the previous version (in disk space) is pretty low (because modern disks just keep getting bigger).

Once you have Java 8 installed, you need to set it as your JVM -

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
```

Then you can verify that you have it selected correctly by

```
java -version
```

Comment: If i had more rep, i'd vote up... I guess it's the thought that counts lol.

Comment: @Catpersonisme That is okay. Send [lawyers, guns and money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawyers,_Guns_and_Money).