# What is the difference between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK?

Tags: java, android, jdk

I was building Android apps on Android Studio when it asked me to remove OpenJDK and install Oracle JDK. Now, I was using OpenJDK for building Cyanogenmod.

If I wipe off OpenJDK and install Oracle JDK, would CM builds break?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22358234/2326627) to understand the key differences between `OpenJDK` and `Oracle JDK`.

If you want to use Oracle Java, you have to install it as Paranoid Panda has suggested. Then you have to set your `Java` environment variables by adding  the following two lines to `~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

If you want, you could also uninstall `OpenJDK` from your machine at all. Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/380300/239377) for the steps to execute to correctly delete it.

Comment: Java and Android build system are two different things. When you build an Android app, at some point it calls the Java compiler you have installed on your machine; it doesn't matter the exact type of compiler, you should only have one installed. So, when you install `Oracle Java` and add `JAVA_HOME` to the `$PATH` list, you are telling the system where to locate your Java compiler. Once done the above step, you can execute `which javac` and `javac -version` to know if the process has gone well.

Comment: That being said, you can safely uninstall OpenJDK if you don't want to use it without affecting the build system used by Android.