# How do I remove openjdk version 11.0.9?

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove openjdk but I can't.  I have tried a lot of times but I can't.  Can someone please help me?

Here is a screenshot of my terminal:

[image: image of terminal]

Comment: Can you add more details ? What did you try and error you get ?

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of your terminal.  Instead, copy-paste the text in the body of your question and use formatting tools or [markdown](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to render the text properly as `code`

Comment: Check at this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335457/how-to-uninstall-openjdk) can help

Answer (score 2):

Remove OpenJDK,

```
sudo apt remove openjdk*
```

Remove OpenJDK along with dependencies,

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove openjdk*
```

Remove OpenJDK and the configuration files

```
sudo apt purge openjdk*
```