# How to remove Java?

Tags: java, uninstall

I installed Java using the terminal and I also installed Java using Wine to try and run a windows App and well didn't work so now I want to remove all Java 100%. How do I go about doing so?

java version "1.7.0_25"

Comment: It depends on what Java you installed..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is the link follow the steps to uninstall java.

[How to remove java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

Hope its helpfull.