# How to uninstall Java 7 binaries installed from Oracle?

Tags: java, uninstall, oracle

I installed Java 7 using the instructions here: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

I want to know how to revert this i.e. uninstall Java 7.

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the instructions on this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/185531/63030

Only thing I did different was that Java's files were in `/usr/local/java` and not `/usr/lib/jvm`.

Answer (score 1):

Execute this command in a Terminal : `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/java/j*.17.0_*/`. This will remove Java binaries.

Now what you have to do is setting valid alternatives for Java commands. For this you can use the [Alternatives Configurator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/galternatives/) program or the (`sudo`) `update-alternatives` command.