# Uninstalling Java (only) after installing Restricted Extras

Tags: xubuntu, java, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I've Googled it and searched a lot but didn't found specifically targeted question in this way. So I really don't want Java. I want to get rid of it. When seeing it in Software Updater, it seems packed in Restricted Extras and is not showing as separate installed. I want to keep all others but uninstall this one. Please help. I'm using Xubuntu 13.10. and updated it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the terminal by Ctrl+Alt+t and wirte

```
java -version
```

it will tell you which java and version you are using then if you have open jdk then write

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk
```

it will remove openJDK from your computer, else leave your java -version output..

for removing  all the Java related packages [click here](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/192102)

Comment: It told me like this:

The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Now there are gcj and openjdk. Should I continue with your solution? BTW Thanks for the reply.

Comment: that simply means java is not been installed yet..

Comment: and java is not even packaged in Ubuntu-restricted-extras..

Comment: How come? In Restricted Extras it is written that it has mp3, mpeg, Java, Flash etc. things. Then how Java is not there? There must be some mistake.

Comment: yeah java is there but only for browser functioning , and games , i was talking about JDK.. and for your problem i have attached a link that would solve your problem for sure..