# Eclipse Error on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, java, eclipse

I have successfully installed Oracle Java 64 bit version on my machine (checked with `java -version`).
Later I have downloaded Eclipse Kepler 64 bit but when I start it, it does not work and it is giving me the Error popup with message `An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/nandkumar/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1384713086093.log`

So I checked log file, see below log file contents :

```
!SESSION Mon Nov 18 00:01:26 IST 2013 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2013-11-18 00:01:26.132
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available.
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:99)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:78)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:191)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:155)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE.<clinit>(SunJCE.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:232)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$3.get(ProviderList.java:147)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList$3.get(ProviderList.java:142)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getPrngAlgorithm(SecureRandom.java:542)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:187)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:155)
    at java.io.File$TempDirectory.<clinit>(File.java:1878)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1987)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.canWrite(Main.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.checkConfigurationLocation(Main.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Please help with this.

Comment: Oracle Java and Ubuntu are not the best friends. I would remove Oracle, install OpenJDK and try to use eclipse. Otherwise, the Eclipse included in the repositories should work.

Comment: I am using latest oracle java with Eclipse kepler and Spring tool suite on ubuntu 13.04, it has some issues with 13.10 ,but works fine with 13.04.

Comment: Could you please explain how you got STS working in 13.10???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what problem was but it got away when I completely removed java(Oracle and Open JDK) using [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/209575). And again I installed Oracle java using [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/209575).

Comment: that is what i have written in my answer.. well its good to know problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is just becouse your JDK(Java Devlopment Kit) is missing JCE (Java Cryptography Env.) functionality .I think some
countries can only obtain "crippled" JDKs like that due to US export control
restrictions.  You can't run Eclipse with such a JDK.  One thing you can
check... in your JDK install, look for a file:

```
/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre/lib/security
```

Make sure that it has a line like this:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

This sets "Sun" as your cryptography provider.  This is usually the default for
a Sun JDK but perhaps it has been turned off in your JDK.

then check out the outputs of

```
java
javac
javaws
```

If it shows an error then you need to install Java again by [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/381986/192102)  the problem is definitly in JDK So install it correctly by downloading Latest Oracle Java from official site as per to your Ubuntu System Architecture and then reinstall eclipse again by following procedure and make sure you have removed previously installed eclipse completely ..

I am assuming that you have downloaded eclipse kepler in Download folder in home,

```
cd Downloads
```

if its for 64 bit then otherwise .gz name would be diffrent for 32 bit

```
tar xvf eclipse-standard-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
sudo mv eclipse /opt
```

provide your password,and make link by

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
```

now just make eclipse.desktop by

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

and paste the following lines for eclipse icon

```
[Desktop Entry]


Name=Eclipse
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=eclipse.desktop
```

Eclipse Kepler is now ready to use.

Comment: hey thanks Sushant! I already had checked `security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun` line which was already present there in file. But it did not work out.

Comment: yeah great the actual problem was in JDK.

Comment: yeah may be conflict between OpenJDK and Oracle Java installations, btw thanks for your valuable time and for help :)

Comment: exactly.. i will remember this for future..

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

I have got the same issue in an AMD64 machine (Ubuntu 12.04). and solved it by a workaround:

copy: files containing '3740' in /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so to ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/

But, be sure the packages : libswt-gtk-3-java & libswt-gtk-3-jni are installed.

sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java

And

sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/

if you have a 32 bits based system : sudo cp /usr/lib/jni/libswt-*3740.so ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/

[here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/359458/)

Comment: hey thanks but I already tried this solution, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

** [ SOLUTION - 1. wrong architecture - 2. java on ubuntu] **

[Problems with Eclipse and updated Java version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395985/problems-with-eclipse-and-updated-java-version/399984#399984)