# Best Practice for Installing Java on Ubuntu / is it secure?

Tags: java, security

Much has been said about the security risks associated with Java. However the burp suite (pen test) depends on Java.

Is it secure to install Java? if so, how to properly do it?

My Ubuntu is a web server and I don't need Java for web services - only for burp suite.

Comment: If you want to know how to install latest oracle Java ,then i can help you and yes its safe , wats the issue with it?

Comment: as i passionately hate Larry Ellison, i installed  'default-jre' using apt-get install. i guess this one should work too. 


my question is not whether the installer is clean - but whether the server is still as in/secure after the installation by default or whether i have to configure it manually. our website does not require java - burp suite does.

java is very vulnerable to all sorts of exploits - that's why we all turn it off when surfing.

my question is not for surfing - but for a webserver & burp...

Answer (score 3):

## Java related security considerations

I think the problem with Java security is first and foremost related to:

- Outdated insecure versions
- Java running as applets within your browser makes you vulnerable to exploits coming from remote.

So to mitigate this you should:

- Install Java from a repository (so you can update with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` later)
- Don't install the Java-Plugin
- .. or disable it with NoScript(Firefox) / NotScript(Chrome)

Since you are installing Java on a server and you won't run a browser there, you will only have to deal with the first problem: So update Java regularly (which you should do with *any* installed software anyway).

## How to install Open-Java

First [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/a/148645/75166). If you haven't done it already.

Then you install Java with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

This will install Java **without** the Java-Plugin.

## How to install Oracle-Java

To get an automatically update-able Java from Oracle, you can you use the PPA provided from webup8.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

[This article](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html) has the details about the Oracle-Java PPA. Unfortunately I don't know how to **not** install the Java-Plugin with this PPA.

Comment: this answers my question completely - if anyone wanna close the question already - feel free to.

thank you madmike and Sushantp606

Comment: Here is how to [close a question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3611/75166)

Comment: I've added the WebUp8-method to install Oracle-Java.

Answer (score 2):

**For installing Latest Oracle Java:**

To check ubuntu system architecture installed

```
$ uname -m
```

or

```
$ arch
```

Download the Oracle Java JDK for Linux. Make sure you select the correct compressed binaries for your system architecture 32-bit or 64-bit (which end in tar.gz).It will be downloaded in Downloads folder in home.So first open nautilus with sudo as

```
sudo nautilus
```

and make a folder java under

```
/usr/local/
```

and then folow the following commands:

```
cd /home/"your_user_name"/Downloads
sudo cp -r jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java
cd /usr/local/java
sudo chmod a+x jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u40-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

At this point you should have two uncompressed binary directories in /usr/local/java check it by

```
ls -a
```

Now edit the system path file by

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

scroll down to the last and add following lines

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

Save and exit and write these commands in terminal to Inform your Ubuntu Linux system where your Oracle Java JDK/JRE is located.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javac
sudo update-alternatives --set javaws /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/javaws
. /etc/profile
```

Now everything is installed just check it by

```
java -version
```

the output must be like

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b40)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Congratulation now its installed.

Comment: +1 for the effort documenting how to do it manually. I've done it like this a few time at the last enterprise. The bad thing is that you have to do it again each time an update comes out. Also, if you don't upgrade, you become vulnerable to the unfixed security issues. The good thing is that you get to know your system better and are in control.

Comment: thanks @MadMike , this is because I luv Ubuntu now, and want to share information i know.