# Netbeans 7.0.1 doesn't work

Tags: netbeans

I installed netbeans 7.0.1 and MySql in ubuntu 13.04 and the first time netbeans start but doesn't create projects. So i close netbeans and restarted but doesn't star. There's is a solution? I need to work with those programs...thanks

Comment: Please type names of programms into terminal and send us messages, maybe someone will help :)

Comment: @dhpasta with Netbeans:netbeans
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xaf87f1ff, pid=7615, tid=2977868608

 JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
 Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
 Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
 Distribution: Ubuntu 13.04, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.13.04.4
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libcairo.so.2+0x1ff]  xcb_render_create_picture+0x1ff
 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /home/lorena/hs_err_pid7615.log
MySql workbench is fine, i mentioned because i need to work with both

Comment: Could you [edit] your question. Comments are undesirable place for adding relevant information. Also add the contents of `/home/lorena/hs_err_pid7615.log`

Answer (score 0):

There are few simmilar bugs on Launchpad for openjdk, one of them has such a solution:

1. Uninstalled Netbeans 7.3;
2. Uninstalled Java 6;
3. Installed Java 7;
4. Installed Netbeans 7.3;

It has been copied from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1206570).

Comment: thank you, now i'm gonna try this. Then i tell you how it go.

Comment: @Lorena How's your problem?

Comment: the same. I made all the steps and netbeans doesn't work. :( maybe if i use eclipse. i don't know.

Comment: `A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000000, pid=8582, tid=2977295168
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 13.04, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.13.04.4
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000`

Comment: I have no idea what to do now

Comment: you know @dhpasta now i can start netbeans, load the IDE, but freezes only when i want to start a new project. And i opened with the terminal and no bugs, or errors appeared. So...or maybe my pc is going crazy or i don't know. Really

Comment: At first came to my mind such a idea: You can open in netbeans some of your old project, clear it and save as other one you want to create instead of creating new one by hitting "start a new project". I'm always looking for such a solutions when I can't repair sth...

Comment: im tired of netbeans, now the bug is back and i don't touch anything. SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xaf9802d2, pid=2940, tid=2977393472 
So, i'm gonna unninstall netbeans and install eclipse. Maybe i can start to make that system...thanks for everything.

Comment: You'r welcome, I like your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have not installed Java correctly test it by -

```
java -version
javac
javaws
```

If there are errors then remove everything and install it as [shown here](https://askubuntu.com/a/381986/192102)

Then install netbeans and mySql.

Comment: There are errors, so i try to uninstall and install everything again. thank you very much,