# Error on installing eclipse from software center

Tags: java, eclipse, software-installation

I have installed eclipse from the software center and when I open it I get the error that sayt to see a log file. The log file is in `~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration` path and says:

```
!SESSION 2013-12-07 18:26:43.336
----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736 java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=it_IT Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk
-arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-12-07 18:26:44.091 !MESSAGE
Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not
load SWT library. Reasons:      no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path    no
swt-gtk in java.library.path    Can't load library:
/home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk-3740.so  Can't load
library: /home/ubuntu/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-gtk.so

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)   at
org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)  at
org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)  at
org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)     at
org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)     at
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)  at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)     at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
    at
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)    at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I have not idea of what could be the problem, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem so called error is in SWT lib, that means your JDK is not installed properly .

Reinstall Java as shown [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/381986/192102)

and then

Install Eclipse as shown [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/382319/192102)

hope it helped you.

Comment: thanks, but the first link isn't about installing java

Comment: Before reinstalling remove JDK completely , if you need help in that , tell me.

Comment: where can I find a guide on how remove JDK?

Comment: if you have installed it directly by adding ppa and then installing oracle java use "sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer" and then use http://askubuntu.com/a/122012/192102