# How to Install apropraite Eclipse on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, java, eclipse

I want to know how can i install Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04LTS as I'm new in both and want Eclipse platform suitable for my

```
java version "1.6.0_38" 
Java(TM) SE Run-time Environment
(build> 1.6.0_38-b05) 
Java Hot Spot(TM) Client
V M (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: any help !!!!!!!

Comment: yep, it's a duplicate

Comment: Thanks , but is there a specific version should i install it as i have jdk1.6.0_38  jre1.6.0_38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is found in the "Ubuntu Software Center".
Just type in "Eclipse" in the search box, then the password, and eclipse will be downloaded for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have described The Easiest But A Bit Lengthy Method of Installing Eclipse Mars IDE on Ubuntu 14.04 is here. It is useful for Beginners in Linux as they don't get well with Proper Terminal Commands.

**Source: [Install Eclipse Mars IDE on Ubuntu](http://www.codingalpha.com/install-eclipse-ide-mars-in-linux-ubuntu/)**

Have a look at the following methods:

1. Download the Eclipse Mars Edition for Linux Ubuntu
2. Goto Terminal and Type:

   ```
   gunzip eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract The Archive using the following Command:

   ```
   tar -xvf eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk.tar
   ```
4. After you've extracted the Eclipse, Change the Directory and Find `eclipse-inst` file by using `ls` command.
5. You can execute the file using the following command:

   ```
   ./eclipse-inst
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Installed Eclipse from Ubuntu software installation center. But when I launched eclipse it gave an error. Soon I realized it is due to incompatibility between JDK and eclipse Indigo(which is the only option in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS software installation center). 
So first I uninstalled eclipse from s/w installation center, then
uninstalled my jdk completely [click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) to know how. After this simply typed OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) in ubuntu software installation center to install open jdk7, and lastly again installed eclipse from s/w installation center. That is it. it all worked well for me.