# What is the command to search for 64-bit installed Java, JRE or OpenJDK?

Tags: command-line

I have a question about the following command:

```
apt-cache search java | awk '{print($1)}' | grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e 'java-common'
```

Owing to my limited IT knowledge, am I right to say that the (ia32-) in the above command refers to 32-bit software? If it is, then I assume that the above command is for 32-bit installed OS.

However I installed a 64-bit OS.

What is the correct parameter for 64-bit software? Is it (amd64-) or (ia-64) or (x86_64-)?

Any expert help is much appreciated.

Comment: `ia32-` won't represent a 32 bit software.It also looks for the package name starting with `ia32-`.The only package that starts with `ia32-` is `ia32-libs`

Comment: **`^`- starting, `?` - optional ,`|` - OR**

Comment: Note that the `|` means "OR" _only_ within the regular expressions above, between the various commands it is a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `apt-cache search` does not search for *installed* packages, it looks for *available* ones, both installed and not installed. Also, the various search patterns you see are not mutually exclusive, so lines matching *any* of them will be printed. Finally, the `?` after `^(ia32-)` means `ia32-` is optional, the expression will match lines that have it *and* lines that don't. So, your command will indeed work for 64 and 32 bit systems.

The equivalent command to look for installed packages only would be:

```
dpkg -l *java* | awk '{print($2)}' | 
    grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' \
      -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e 'java-common'
```

But don't use that. In Debian derived systems such as Ubuntu, there is a special tool for this, `update-java-alternatives` which, when run with the `-l` option will list installed Java environments:

```
 update-java-alternatives -l
```

On my system, for example, this prints:

```
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
jdk-7-oracle-x64 317 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-x64
```

Comment: Thanks for such your answer and detailed explanation. Is there a way for me to award you more points?

Comment: What programming language was the command written in? C? C++? Basic? C#? The whole command resembles a string of art with ^ | and *

Comment: The language is basic shell scripting and regular expressions. The `^` is a regular expression trick, it means `match the beginning of a line`, the `|` are pipes which pass the output of one command as input to another. `*` is a wildcard, it means `0 or more`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basic shell scripting is based on a programming language, no?

Comment: No, it _is_ a simple programming language but all the strange stuff you see here are regular expressions, the shell part is what pass the input of one command to another (using `|`). For a very nice tutorial on regular expressions, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: If you have time, could you help provide an answer to me please? The link to the webpage is http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java and my question starts with the words `The command sudo apt-get -y autoremove removes many other packages that I need. Is it OK to just ignore this command? Or could you provide a "gentler" command that does not remove packages other than those have Java in them?`

Comment: @n00b please post your own question and I or someone else will be happy to answer it. Do not ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Could you recast your answer `dpkg -l *java* | awk '{print($2)}' | 
    grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' \
      -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e 'java-common'` in code form so that there is only one string? (See how I did it in my question.) I find it easier to copy and past if the command were in code form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @n00b it _is_ in "code form", notice the `\ ` at the end of the line, that enables you to paste multi line commands. You can simply copy/paste it as is directly into your terminal.