# How to remove openjdk 6 from ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: java, openjdk

When I do

```
sudo apt-cache search openjdk
```

I got:

```
default-jdk - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit
default-jdk-doc - Standard Java or Java compatible Development Kit (documentation)
default-jre - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime
default-jre-headless - Standard Java or Java compatible Runtime (headless)
icedtea-7-jre-jamvm - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
icedtea-7-plugin - web browser plugin based on OpenJDK and IcedTea to execute Java applets
openjdk-7-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-7-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-7-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-7-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-7-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-7-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-7-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
java-package - Utility for creating Java Debian packages
freemind - Java Program for creating and viewing Mindmaps
icedtea-6-jre-cacao - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Cacao
icedtea-6-jre-jamvm - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using JamVM
icedtea-6-plugin - web browser plugin based on OpenJDK and IcedTea to execute Java applets
jtreg - Regression Test Harness for the OpenJDK platform
jvm-7-avian-jre - lightweight virtual machine using the OpenJDK class library
libreoffice - office productivity suite (metapackage)
openjdk-6-dbg - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)
openjdk-6-demo - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)
openjdk-6-doc - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation
openjdk-6-jdk - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
openjdk-6-jre - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT
openjdk-6-jre-headless - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)
openjdk-6-jre-lib - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
openjdk-6-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
openjdk-6-source - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files
openjdk-7-jre-zero - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark
uwsgi-app-integration-plugins - plugins for integration of uWSGI and application
uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-6 - Java plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 6)
uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-7 - Java plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 7)
uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-6 - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 6)
uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-7 - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 7)
openjdk-7-jre-lib - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
```

I tried to remove jdk-6 using:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jdk
```

I got result as:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openjdk-6-jdk' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libc6-i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I want to uninstall `openjdk-6-jdk`, but should not remove `openjdk-7-jdk`, expecting solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to completely uninstall Java?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-cache` performs a variety of operations on APT's package cache, it won't list the installed packages.

To see if an `openjdk` package is actually installed on your system you can just type in a terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep openjdk
```

Comment: i done what you said, but i am getting same result

Comment: could you please attach to your original question the result of my command?

Comment: i didn't any response when executing your command, but after i tried the above i told, but i am getting same result as you saw above

Comment: It only means that `openjdk` was not installed on your system, so there's nothing to remove. Could you please accept and up-vote (^) my answer? Thanks.

Comment: With your reputation level, you can also vote on answers, just click the (^) mark above the 0 next to the checkbox. Thanks again