# Installing OpenJDK on (chr)Lubuntu 14.04 on Acer C710

Tags: lubuntu, software-installation, openjdk, chromebook

Completely new to Linux, bear with me. I've just this morning succeeded in getting Lubuntu on my Acer C710, thanks to the wonderful script over [here](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html).

I'm trying to see how Minecraft will run, which requires Java. I started by trying to install Oracle, but it was the full JDK rather than just the JRE, so I uninstalled it. I don't fully understand the instructions for installing the JRE (being as it isn't on the repository and such).

Next I tried to install OpenJDK 6's and 7's JREs. I tried from the repository, the LSC, and the Synaptic package manager. All of them bring up errors during the install. The repository, for example:

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  abiword-common fonts-lyx libabiword-3.0 libchamplain-0.12-0
  libchamplain-gtk-0.12-0 libgdome2-0 libgdome2-cpp-smart0c2a
  libgtkmathview0c2a liblink-grammar4 libloudmouth1-0 libmhash2 libots0
  libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libtelepathy-glib0 libtidy-0.99-0
  libwmf0.2-7 libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libwv-1.2-4 libyajl2
  link-grammar-dictionaries-en xul-ext-ubufox
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/72.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package tzdata-java (--configure):
 package tzdata-java is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64:
 openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 depends on tzdata-java; however:
  Package tzdata-java is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jre-headless:
 default-jre-headless depends on openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7~u3-2.1.1); however:
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Package openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.
```

It goes on like that for a while. Trying to uninstall bits of these programs seems to have brought up a few errors talking about the same half-installed errors, and some bits of the programs are there and won't go away, but do nothing anyway - the policy tools, and the option to open my .jar in 6 or 7's JREs (but, as said, this does nothing - not even an error message).

I'm floundering for what more I can actually say. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you try 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them as suggested in your output? This would help clean things up a bit. You might also search for dpkg dependancy problems as I assume that's been asked and answered.

Comment: This may also be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: @ElderGeek: The `apt-get autoremove` bit is for the packages listed above that message, and doesn't affect the current operation.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f`, or maybe `sudo apt-get install tzdata-java`?

Answer (score 1):

Clean house and start from scratch see the excellent answer by Eric Carvalho on this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) on how to clean up the mess.

Then open software center and install Open JDK Java 7 Runtime [image: JavaInstall]

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning house was a good idea. I fixed this by manually deleting the tzdata-java package from the terminal, with `sudo rm -rf tzdata-java`. It didn't work from the file explorer, but worked with sudo on the terminal. When I went to install Java, it brought up some error messages about that package, but I ignored them and it installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to start button equivalent\System tools\Lubuntu Software Centre
Search for openjdk Java 7 runtime and install it, I tested this on my Fujitsu Lifebook and it does run Minecraft. Also the Acer c710 should have no problems running Minecraft, however Ubuntu will actually give you better performance in game.