# too many JDK's after installing openjdk-8

Tags: uninstall, openjdk

I upgraded to Ubuntu gnome 14.10 this weekend. I've been curious to try out JavaFX, and noticed that there is now an openjfx package available. So I apt-get installed openjdk-8-jdk and openjfx and tried it out. Everything seemed to work fine, and I decided I didn't need another openjdk any longer. So I apt-get removed openjdk-7-jdk. When checking update-alternatives --config java, I noticed I now suddenly have three jdk's installed:

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
```

I'm not sure if I can run into problems if I have three different JDK's installed (except for the fact that it uses space on a not-so-large SSD), or if removing them can result in unexpected issues. I would like to remove two of them, but should I? And how can I? I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java), but I don't want to uninstall everything, just the jdk 6 and 7. Or is it best to just uninstall everything, and reinstall jdk 8 afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem to have multiple JDKs installed. I have at least one release of 6, 7 and 8 on my machine (the oracle version). Generally use the latest for most things but there are sometimes have to work on legacy software.

Comment: I managed to remove jdk 6 with the software center. I'll just leave jdk 7 and 8 installed for now. I have indeed not noticed any problems with it.