# Can not launch Android Studio

Tags: 14.10, jdk

Showing the message

'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath.
 Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

how can i solve it

show me how  install jdk properly

Answer (score 1):

You can install JDK using following command :

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

And then run

> sudo update-alternatives --config java

command and select JDK instead of JRE. And then try to run

> studio.sh

Hope it helps

Comment: Perhaps consider using: `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`
instead of specifying version 7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you've installed the java sdk, and not just the jre
2. Ensure the JAVA_HOME environment path has the correct path after the sdk is installed

Comment: my friend but i do not know how to install them

Comment: There are some very good instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

Answer (score 0):

I removed android studio, Umake and zip. Then I followed the instructions on this link [How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java). Then installed java7 jdk form software center. Finally i re-installed android studio using umake. Now it works like a charm!