# Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: You have loaded library [...].so which might have disabled stack guard

Tags: java, virtualization

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning:
You have loaded library /tmp/libnetty-transport-native-epoll7650900490225298142.so
 which might have disabled stack guard.
The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 
'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.`
```

This shows up on startup of my Minecraft server

```
Ubuntu 14.04LTS 32bit java1.8.0_40
```

I tried [uninstalling java completely](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/343730).

And [reinstalling](http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa/).

'execstack' is not a command in terminal or java

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just attempted to correct this issue on my server.
Did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prelink
```

then ran the execstack command only to be told the `file doesn't exist`

Manually checked the `/tmp` directory and the file does not exist so it wasn't a path error.

How a file can be loaded that doesn't exist is a puzzle unless it was loaded during a java update and then erased....

Comment: In my case, the file at path exists but still see the warning message.  Any idea why?