# How to remove the binary format already installed by openjdk-7

Tags: java, ubuntu-touch

Platform: Ubuntu 15.04.

During building android 4.4.2_r1/ or phablet, it's stopped by the message:

"You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.
Your version is: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar .
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6."
Output:

> $ make j 4
>   ..................................................................................................................................................
>
> Checking build tools versions...
>
> ---
>
> You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
>   of java.
>    Your version is: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar .
>
> The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
>
> ---
>
> build/core/main.mk:168: *** stop.  Stop.

I already remove/ uninstall all the openjdk, but everytime check java version, the output is

> $ java -version
>
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>
> java version "1.6.0_45"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

If reinstalling the oracle-java6:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall oracle-java6-installer

during the progress, I'm noticed with the message:

> "update-binfmts: warning: current package is oracle-java6, but binary format already installed by openjdk-7"

If apply "sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk", the output:

> :~$ sudo dpkg --list | grep -i jdk
>
> ii  oracle-java6-installer    6u45-0~webupd8~8           all    Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 6
>
> rc  oracle-java7-installer    7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~0   all    Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 7

I think, may the "binary format already installed by openjdk-7" remain existing be the cause.

So, the question is: how to remove the binary format, which already installed by openjdk-7?

Comment: Why is that off topic?

Answer (score 4):

The trouble's fixed, steps I performed:

1. `sudo rm /var/lib/binfmts/jar`
2. Remove the package `jayatana` from Ubuntu software center.
3. Remove all the Java related packages (Sun, Oracle, OpenJDK, IcedTea plugins, GIJ):

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   apt-cache search java | awk '{print($1)}' | grep -E -e '^(ia32-)?(sun|oracle)-java' -e '^openjdk-' -e '^icedtea' -e '^(default|gcj)-j(re|dk)' -e '^gcj-(.*)-j(re|dk)' -e 'java-common' | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove
   sudo apt-get -y autoremove
   ```
4. Purge config files:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{print($2)}' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
   ```
5. Remove Java config and cache directory:

   ```
   sudo bash -c 'ls -d /home/*/.java' | xargs sudo rm -rf
   ```
6. Remove manually installed JVMs:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm/*
   ```
7. `sudo apt-get update`
8. Reboot
9. Re-install the oracle-java6:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
   ```

Reference: [How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

Comment: It's a good answer. But I think you don't need a reboot.

Comment: Agree A.B., it may not be necessary for an reboot.

Answer (score 4):

Running this command did it for me:

```bash
sudo update-binfmts --package openjdk-7 --remove jar /usr/bin/jexec
sudo dpkg-reconfigure openjdk-13-jre-headless
```

See http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=3137.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with remnants of openjdk-11 conflicting with openjdk-17. The above solution pointed me in the right direction but was slightly incomplete at least in my case.

First I found the remnant openjdk-11 packages:

```
dpkg --list | grep openjdk-11
```

Then I purged those packages, e.g.:

```
sudo apt purge openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

Next I updated binfmts to remove openjdk-11:

```
sudo update-binfmts --package openjdk-11 --remove jar /usr/bin/jexec
```

The solution above uses dpkg-reconfigure but I did reinstall instead:

```
sudo apt reinstall openjdk-17-jre openjdk-17-jre-headless
```