# Java: Error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so

Tags: java

I tried installing openjdk6, openjdk7, oracle8... But always the same error when I want to execute java, for example with `java -version`:

> java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried with symbolic links trying to get to recognize `libjli.so` but it didn't work

After uninstalling all versions, following the steps shown here [How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) , and installing again, can't make the error disappear. Even if I uninstall it all again, if I write in terminal `java -version` it stills throw me the same error.

I'm doing all of this with user sudo.

Thank you

**EDIT:** Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server

**EDIT 2:** Installing Openjdk7, Oracle7 and Oracle8, using `update-alternatives --config java` tells me that (in Spanish, but I'll try to translate, 3 lines of information)

"there is only one alternative in the group of java links in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` Nothing to configure."

"update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` because the Java links' group is broken"

"update-alternatives: warning: `/usr/bin/java` will not be substituted by a link"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
rm /usr/bin/java
update-alternatives --config java
```

Now it works by removing that binary, it was causing problems. Doesn't know if `update-alternatives` had any effect, but the last warning didn't show.

Answer (score 8):

I meet this issue in a chroot environment, and fix it by this action

```
mount --bind /dev /myroot/dev
mount --bind /proc /myroot/proc
```

Comment: I only needed to mount `/proc` into my small chroot for this particular issue.  `/dev` and `/dev/pts` also helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem when I made a hard-link to the java executable and tried to execute it.  I'm presuming it was looking for its libraries using a relative path to the executable binary.

I tried both of these options, and each worked for me:

- Putting the hard-link in the same directory as the java binary and running it from there (/usr/lib/jvm/openjre-8/bin in my case)
- Creating and using a symbolic link instead of a hard link
  (ie. with `ln -s $(which java) /usr/bin/${my_binary_name}`)

Comment: I'm presuming the accepted solution fixes it because it creates a symbolic link instead of the copy or hard-link of the java binary..

Comment: A variant of the symbolic link fix worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same question on CentOS when I installed the jdk1.8 .

I solved it by:

first, you should give the file execute permission,then install and config it.

```
chmod a+x jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

actually,the `libji.so` file is in the directory

```
jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
```

Comment: Why would giving execute permission on a archive file be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

what working with me is not using the java under

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/
```

but the usage of the java under

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

which already has a link to the missing lib .

This happened for me when using oracle jdk 8 v 191 along with eclipse

and it act the same for openjdk you may use

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem upon launching a fresh install of the Arduino IDE 
(even after running *also* the script `arduino-linux-setup.sh`).

Everything was installed under `$HOME/Downloads/arduino-1.8.12/`.

In this folder there was a `java/bin/java` executable, *apparently* looking for a `../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so`, so I tried to give it one as a soft symlink to `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/jli/libjli.so`, and *it solved the problem*.

I came to this solution on trying to reproduce under the install folder some of the standard Java folder structure.

Comment: “[mkdir … &] cd ~/Downloads/arduino-1.8.12/java/lib/amd64/jli”, then “ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/jli/libjli.so”.