# Completely uninstall java on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: java, 15.10, software-uninstall

I have a problem uninstall java in my system .
I tried this [How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) but I always get the same error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre (>= 7~u3-2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed

 default-jre-headless : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7~u3-2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and when I type `apt-get -f install`  I get this error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsl0ldbl libguvcview-1.1-1 libsdl2-2.0-0 libwebcam0
  linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic uvcdynctrl
  uvcdynctrl-data
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  openjdk-7-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei ttf-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  openjdk-7-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
74 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 55,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 287924 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar' to '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong because I cant install anything .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says there was an error unpacking an archive. In this case, that's probably because it didn't download correctly. Delete the mentioned archive file and retry:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: That completly fix my problem thank you @Olathe .To avoid future problems like this can you explain me why that happened ?I didn't install tha package ,just woke up and there it was .

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't be avoided, since errors can creep into files due to a bad download or disk problems and since `apt-get` isn't smart enough to throw the bad file away and redownload it.