# Minecraft server unable to locate java after Ubuntu update to 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash, java, minecraft, openjdk

I've been running a minecraft server on ubuntu for some time. This morning, **I updated to 16.04** and the server won't launch anymore. The error I'm getting in the terminal is:

```
bash:/usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

**What I've done since getting the error:**

```
sudo apt-get install default-java
```

didn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

this didn't work either. I saw someone on askubuntu suggesting the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
```

Tried it and it didn't work either. I'm kind of just throwing stuff at the wall until something sticks, which I know isn't the right way to go about this!

I'm not quite sure what to try next, can someone give me a hand? Thanks, all!

Comment: Have you tried `whereis java` or `java -version` to be sure `java` is still where it should be?

Comment: just did, it returns:
    "java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz"

Comment: please could you paste the full error message as is from the `minecraft`

Comment: please run this `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`,  then `sudo ap-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install oracle-java<version-of-java>-installer`

Comment: @George I did a purge of all java related packages (http://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) and installed oracle's java, as you suggested. I've got it working now. You da real MVP...

Comment: let me put down the solution so you can mark the answer as the accept one, glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purge all java packages that are installed already by following the instructions here: [askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-j‌​ava](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-j%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bava)

Then, do the following to install Oracle's java:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java<version-of-java>-installer
```