# How do I reinstall java after completely uninstalling it?

Tags: java

I followed a guide on completely uninstalling java but now I want to reinstall it again is that still possible using only the terminal because my computer won't boot anymore because of it?
I used this guide [How to completely uninstall Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)

```
dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64

dpkg:dependency problems prevent configuration openjdk-8-jre:amd64 depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 
package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured
```

I tried using the Linux mint USB drive i booted with the very first time and used bootrepair
Here is the pastebin link if it's usefull:
http://paste2.org/AtCm82xj

If all else fails is there a way for me to use that drive but to keep nu files?

Comment: Java is not required to boot Ubuntu. Please describe what exactly you did. There are many ways of installing Java and just as much to remove it. We can't help you if we don't know know what you screwed up or what you tried to do at least.

Answer (score -1):

Try to login as guest. If that is successful, it would seem to suggest your personal user account is requiring java during boot and you may need to verify the bash startup files e.g. bashrc etc