# java unable to open .jar files

Tags: java

i run ubuntu 16.04 and i am trying to execute 'minecraft.jar' located at my desktop. i right click and choose to open it using 'JDK java 8 runtime' but no luck. i then try to execute from the terminal:

```
s@s-Inspiron-3543:~/Desktop$ java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

and get the following message:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
* default-jre
* gcj-5-jre-headless
* openjdk-8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.8-jre-headless
* gcj-4.9-jre-headless
* openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

so, i installed and again i get the same... when i check for the java version:

```
 s@s-Inspiron-3543:~$ update-java-alternatives -l
```

i get either

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64    1081  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk- amd64
```

or if i use the 'java version' again i am told where to install it from...

any ideas???

thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 9, OpenJDK or otherwise, is still under development, last I checked, and is ***very*** likely to be buggy - it's ***very very likely*** this is due to you using Java 9 and not a Stable Release of Java (such as Java 8).

Consider switching back to Java 8, and not use Java 9 since it's still in 'development' and not yet released.  (This applies to Oracle Java as well).

Failing that, remove ***all*** Java packages, and try reinstalling them all with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk
```

... which should install all the Java 8 files again and make it usable once again.

Comment: i rolled back to java 8 and edited my question. please have another look...

Comment: @StamatisDiamantopoulos How did you install the Java executable?  It seems to me like it doesn't want to put things in the correct paths.

Comment: i completey removed all java traces (i hope) following this:https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java and i am reinstalling using: sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk . which results in openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode) and now it works!!! thanks for the help - it partly resolved the matter : )