# I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and is dual booted. I can't install Netbeans!

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle, netbeans

Netbeans didn't work at first because I didn't have Java installed and now, I have the JDK 10 installed and it won't open -,-. Before I installed JDK 10, I installed JDK 8, it worked fine, but when I can't do stuff after the installation because when I started the app, it says I have to disable the modules and stuff. I am really lost because I am new to Ubuntu, I used to be a Mac user and I dual-booted Ubuntu. I had trouble installing a lot of things because it requires shell (or Terminal) commands. ESPECIALLY Java! Why doesn't it have an installer like the one for Macs and Windows? But I didn't care so I took the matter bare-hand. Instead of fixing, I think I made it far-more worse! Please help me!
P.S. Now, Netbeans can't even start! And I read the logs, it said, " Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default."

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! To aid in problem diagnosis, specific error messages, warnings, etc can be a lot more helpful than statements like "it says I have to disable the modules and stuff".  If you edit your question, remove the 'story', and add details, you have a much better change of getting help.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040049/how-to-install-netbeans-from-umake/1040151?s=1|0.0000#1040151 .

Comment: I use or used Netbeans 8.2

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans and Java versions seems to be either incompatible or either of the two is broken. Ubuntu's default jdk is JDK 10 but has Netbeans 8.1. Also, [release notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#req_sw) of Netbeans 8.2 clearly states: *The tested JDK for this release is JDK 8u101 for Windows, Linux, and OS X. The 8.2 version of the IDE cannot be installed or run on the JDK older than JDK 8.*

**Note**: I have also tried using Netbeans with JDK8 which is already present in repository and it's also having some sort of bugs.

I have also observed that not only Netbeans but Eclipse is also having some problems. So, what I did is first of all I uninstalled java completely from my system following steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/816190). Then downloaded Netbeans+JDK8 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html). I assume that your downloads go in `~/Downloads` folder.

Then follow these steps:

```
cd Downloads
chmod +x jdk-8u171-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh
./jdk-8u171-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh
```

#### For Installation of Netbeans 9.0 see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076408/how-do-i-install-netbeans-9-0).

Comment: I somehow installed JDK 10 (javac 10.0.1) and BlueJ works, but I get an failed to load module: "overlay scrollbar" thing. Netbeans still doesn't work. Now, it won't even open... Should I try IntelliJ community edition?

Comment: In my system, IntelliJ was also experiencing some problems. In my case it was starting but doesn't respond on compiling a program. I strongly recommend you to downgrade your JDK since I think JDK 10 on Linux is having problems at this point of time. The solution I have provided in the answer solved my problems in Netbeans and Eclipse. If you want to use JDK10 I would rather suggest you to wait till Ubuntu's next update.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10? I am dual-booted, and I'm not sure if I can because... I'm dual-booted. Also, I heard something about openjdk what's that? Is that a better alternative? How can I install it?

Comment: No, I mean 18.04.1 which is scheduled in last week of July. It does have anything to do with dual boot. My laptop is also dual booted and I use Ubuntu most of the time. Why do you need JDK10? I suggest you to try the above solution. I think openjdk will not solve your problem. If you still want openjdk , open Terminal and type `sudo apt search openjdk`. Decide which jdk you want to install and then type `sudo apt-get install package_name`.

Comment: BlueJ now really works flawlessly, but I still prefer Netbeans. Netbeans works now, but some plugins don't work. Thanks anyways!