# how to install netbeans from umake?

Tags: software-installation, java, snap, netbeans, ubuntu-make

How do I install netbeans from `umake`?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ umake ide netbeans
Choose installation path: /home/thufir/.local/share/umake/ide/netbeans
thufir@dur:~$
```

System info:

```
    thufir@dur:~$ 
    thufir@dur:~$ netbeans

    Command 'netbeans' not found, but can be installed with:

    sudo apt install netbeans

    thufir@dur:~$ 
    thufir@dur:~$ snap info ubuntu-make
    name:      ubuntu-make
    summary:   Setup your development environment on ubuntu easily
    publisher: didrocks
    license:   unknown
    description: |
      Ubuntu Make provides a set of functionality to setup,
      maintain and personalize your developer environment easily. It will handle
      all dependencies, even those which aren't in Ubuntu itself, and install
      latest versions of the desired and recommended tools.
      .
      This is the latest master from ubuntu make, freshly built from
      https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make. It may contain even unreleased
      features!
    commands:
      - ubuntu-make.umake
    snap-id:   GFBbjr1cRDoT3KSiuwGirj83ReKSSd1J
    tracking:  stable
    refreshed: 2018-05-22T02:03:51-07:00
    installed:   master (367) 13MB classic
    channels:                 
      stable:    master (367) 13MB classic
      candidate: ↑                 
      beta:      ↑                 
      edge:      master (363) 13MB classic
    thufir@dur:~$ 
    thufir@dur:~$ sdk ls java

    ================================================================================
    Available Java Versions
    ================================================================================
         9.0.7-zulu                                                                    
         9.0.4-openjdk                                                                 
     > * 8.0.172-zulu                                                                  
         8.0.171-oracle                                                                
         7.0.181-zulu                                                                  
         6.0.107-zulu                                                                  
         10.0.1-zulu                                                                   
         10.0.1-oracle                                                                 
         10.0.0-openjdk                                                                
         1.0.0-rc1-graal                                                               






    ================================================================================
    + - local version
    * - installed
    > - currently in use
    ================================================================================
    thufir@dur:~$ 
    thufir@dur:~$ java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_172"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.30.0.1-linux64) (build 1.8.0_172-b01)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.30.0.1-linux64) (build 25.172-b01, mixed mode)
    thufir@dur:~$ 
    thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
    javac 1.8.0_172
    thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ umake ide netbeans
Choose installation path: /home/thufir/.local/share/umake/ide/netbeans
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ netbeans

Command 'netbeans' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install netbeans

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap info ubuntu-make
name:      ubuntu-make
summary:   Setup your development environment on ubuntu easily
publisher: didrocks
license:   unknown
description: |
  Ubuntu Make provides a set of functionality to setup,
  maintain and personalize your developer environment easily. It will handle
  all dependencies, even those which aren't in Ubuntu itself, and install
  latest versions of the desired and recommended tools.
  .
  This is the latest master from ubuntu make, freshly built from
  https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make. It may contain even unreleased
  features!
commands:
  - ubuntu-make.umake
snap-id:   GFBbjr1cRDoT3KSiuwGirj83ReKSSd1J
tracking:  stable
refreshed: 2018-05-22T02:03:51-07:00
installed:   master (367) 13MB classic
channels:                 
  stable:    master (367) 13MB classic
  candidate: ↑                 
  beta:      ↑                 
  edge:      master (363) 13MB classic
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sdk ls java

================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     9.0.7-zulu                                                                    
     9.0.4-openjdk                                                                 
 > * 8.0.172-zulu                                                                  
     8.0.171-oracle                                                                
     7.0.181-zulu                                                                  
     6.0.107-zulu                                                                  
     10.0.1-zulu                                                                   
     10.0.1-oracle                                                                 
     10.0.0-openjdk                                                                
     1.0.0-rc1-graal                                                               






================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -v
Unrecognized option: -v
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_172"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.30.0.1-linux64) (build 1.8.0_172-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.30.0.1-linux64) (build 25.172-b01, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo update-alternatives --verbose --config java
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ umake --version
18.05+snap367
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_172
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm your results with Snap version of Ubuntu make, so let's remove it

```
sudo snap remove ubuntu-make
```

And then install version from repository

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

Then install NetBeans IDE with `umake` command:

```
umake ide netbeans
```

Then log-out or reboot.
You can find NetBeans in *Applications->Programming->Netbeans IDE* or run it with `netbeans` command.

Comment: yeah, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make does say it's not working with snap...blech.

Comment: I wrote [self-answered Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040380/66509) about the problem to make it more universal.