# Which version of Ubuntu Make should I use - from APT or from Snap?

Tags: software-installation, 17.10, 18.04, snap, ubuntu-make

Following the last question ["how to install netbeans from umake?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040049/how-to-install-netbeans-from-umake) I have the simply question:

which version of Ubuntu Make should I use - from APT or from Snap?

---

**Note for close-voters:**  we have illustrations that Snap version of Ubuntu Make is broken, so it is not opinion-based and is on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was noted by @Thufir in the comment [below the answer to the aforementioned question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040151/66509)   - 
[Official Ubuntu Make Wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) says that Snap package is not working in 17.10:

> **Installing Ubuntu Make**
>
> You can install the snap package (not working at the moment on 17.10)
>
> ```
> $ snap install ubuntu-make
> ```

Moreover as we have already discovered - it does not work in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS too.
I reported [issue 554 to the GitHub ubuntu/ubuntu-make bug-tracker](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/554) about this problem.

So one should remove Snap version of Ubuntu Make with

```
sudo snap remove ubuntu-make
```

and then install version from repository

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

and afterwards install the application with `umake` command.