# how to install Netbeans 9+ from ubuntu-make or umake?

Tags: software-installation, java, snap, ubuntu-mate, netbeans

*context:  rather than downloading IDE's and SDK's manually, where possible, I prefer to use automation such as:  rVM, SDKman, snap, and umake or ubuntu make.  The scope of this question is limited to tools like this, such as apt and not to manual downloads.*

How do I install `Netbeans` 9+ using `umake`?

I installed `umake` with `apt` because `snap` has [problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/1040049/45156) with `umake`.

Java 11 was installed with `SDKman`, although I also installed `8.0.192-zulu` and `9.0.7-zulu` as well.

Ubuntu make only installs `Netbeans` 8.2.

How do I get `umake` to download Netbeans 9?

> Ubuntu Make
>
> Ubuntu Make is a command line tool which allows you to download the
>   latest version of popular developer tools on your installation,
>   installing it alongside all of the required dependencies (which will
>   only ask for root access if you don't have all the required
>   dependencies installed already), enable multi-arch on your system if
>   you are on a 64 bit machine, integrate it with the Unity launcher.
>   Basically, one command to get your system ready to develop with!

Since I'm at version 8.2 for `Netbeans`, presumably there's a better way to utilize `umake`.

```
thufir@dur:~$  
thufir@dur:~$ netbeans
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/home/thufir/.local/share/umake/ide/netbeans/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
^C
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 11.0.1
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~$
```

Maybe I should downgrade Java:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1093681/45156

and then re-install `NB`.  I don't see how that would *update* netbeans, however.

*footnote:  actually, `Netbeans` 8.2 installs fine from the snap version of `ubuntu-make` or `umake`.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetBeans doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049383/netbeans-doesnt-work)

Comment: Not really a duplicate because it's confined to using ubuntu make.  I'll update at a later point.  My two cents, at least.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) "The XY problem is asking about your attempted *solution* rather than your *actual problem*."

Comment: @karel I believe this isn't a duplicate since it not only focuses on "Netbeans doesn't work' but the reason why umake can't install v9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update (8 April 2019):**
Apache Netbeans (incubating) is now available via ubuntu-make. As they say, latest version, You can now install Netbeans 11.0 using ubuntu-make. For that, run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake ide netbeans
```

---

**Historical answer**:

According to [Ubuntu-make's official repository on GitHub](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) last time Netbeans data such as link was updated/committed on 30 March 2017 while Netbeans 9.0 was released on 29 July 2018. So, I believe as of now it is impossible to install Netbeans 9.0 via ubuntu-make until it updates the details. You'll find that all folders [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/tree/master/tests/data/server-content) which contain details about Netbeans have details of version 8.2.

Also, according to Netbeans 8.2 official [release notes](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/82/relnotes.html#req_sw):

> The tested JDK for this release is JDK 8u101 for Windows, Linux, and OS X. The 8.2 version of the IDE cannot be installed or run on the JDK older than JDK 8.

So, I think its better to downgrade the Java and use Netbeans 8.2 or install Netbeans 9.0 using [other methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076408/how-do-i-install-netbeans-9-0).

Comment: it installed and runs, but is 8.x, not 9.   Odd that ubuntu make doesn't update netbeans.  grrr.  thanks for the deep dive into GitHub.  I had no idea how to get more info on that.  Thanks, also, for confirming incompatibility between JDK and NB versions.

Comment: @Thufir You can make a request to update Netbeans on GitHub.