# How to reinstall Java after complete uninstall

Tags: software-installation, java

I completely uninstalled Java following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java) post. Unfortunately, I am no longer able to reinstall Java.

To reinstall Java, I ran the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install default-jre
```

When I now try to check the version of Java with the command

```
$ java -version
```

I get the following output:

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

However, when (re)running `sudo apt install default-jre`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version (2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Any help on how to reinstall Java after completely uninstalling via [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java)? I already read many articles on the internet but I am not able to resolve this issue.

The output of the command

```
$ apt list --installed | egrep 'jdk|jre'
```

results in:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

default-jdk/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
default-jdk-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
default-jre/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
default-jre-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jdk/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.4+11-1ubuntu2~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-11-jdk-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.4+11-1ubuntu2~18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.4+11-1ubuntu2~18.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 11.0.4+11-1ubuntu2~18.04.3 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-8-jdk/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-8-jdk-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-8-jre/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-8-jre-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that following that answer you deleted all the Java related binaries but didn't actually removed OpenJDK packages. You can reinstall them by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall default-jre default-jdk default-jre-headless default-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
```