# Java process consuming too much ram in background, how to remove it?

Tags: apt, 20.04, java, openjdk

My PC has been crashing a lot of times recently, it suddenly stops responding and after a few seconds, it asks me to force quit some apps. At first, I thought it was a problem with VSCode since it always happens when I'm editing something on it, but it recently has happened with other apps like Spotify or my browser.

When I used the `top` command, I noticed there is this Java process that is consuming more than half of my RAM and I think this could be the reason for the crashes I've been experiencing. The thing is, that I don't know how to get rid of it.

[image: this java process here]

I tried killing the process with the `kill` command hundreds of times, but it keeps appearing there whenever I use the top command. I tried [these commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/1673712) and also manually removed anything related to jdk, openjdk, etc. using the `apt-get remove` command.

I restarted the computer, and the process is still there. I don't know what else I can do.

`pstree` says the full command path is `/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java`, but the *elasticsearch* folder doesn't even exist in there. I looked with the `apt list --installed` and did not find any elasticsearch in there. The pstree command only shows this:

[image]

Comment: check out with `ps aux` to see the entire command (you also can pus `c` in top for that), then you will see the path for tha java app too. But if it starts again and again something starting it, check out with `pstree` what is its parent process.

Comment: Thanks for answering @redseven, it says full command path is "/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk/bin/java", but the folder "elasticsearch" doesn't even exist in there. I also looked with the `apt list --installed` and did not find any elasticsearch in there. The `psetree`command only shows [this](https://imgur.com/9zizocG)

Comment: So did you installed elasticsearch? It may be running in a container, that's why you don't see the path...
`docker ps`

Comment: Thanks @redseven, there was indeed an elasticsearch container set to start automatically on boot, i changed the restart policy with the command `docker update --restart=no <my-container>` and now it's stopped.