# UPNP / DLNA (client) player recommendations?

Tags: software-recommendation

Since neither VLC stable / VLC nightly builds / Totem with Coherence Plugin work properly in oneiric I'm searching for an alternative to watch media streamed from my seagate dockstar using minidlna as a server.

The only client that works is XBMC, but that's much of an overkill and stops me from doing other tasks. Atm I'm working around this with samba shares, but it baffles me that both a Playstation 3 and Windows 7 Laptop work better together with my debian based media server than my linux desktop in this regard.

Comment: you can give Kodi (https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=kodi)

I know that it is a sucessor to XMBC but Debian / Ubuntu Users should give it a try. It has a couple of window modes and does an excellent job.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Recently VLC Version 2.0 was released. This Release features a fully functional UPNP / DLNA Player that works without bugs. I'm using it on Ubuntu and Archlinux and it works just fine with my minidlna player.

To use VLC start the Playlist (`View` -> `Playlist`; `Ctrl + L`) and then select `Local Network` -> `Universal Plug 'n' Play`. However, be advised that VLCs implementation first downloads all the library information before you can select anything. Depending on the size of the library that actually might take several minutes and longer.

VLC might require to have been launched with `--miface=INTERFACE` flag, because on some machines VLC uses the wrong interface by default. You can find the correct interface name from `ifconfig`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - VLC shows my server, but won't let me browse it.

Comment: If your library is large you may have to give it some time. Click on your server and wait a couple of minutes, for some reason VLC is really slow when it comes to your accessing a library for the first time.

Comment: It should display a status bar or some sort of loading icon. I can't even see if it's worth waiting.

Comment: VLC also doesn't work for me. As I already commented https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=kodi Kodi does the job excellently

Comment: Mine flickers for a split second and goes back to just the "playlist" heading (NAS computer name). No videos come up. I waited. Enabled full verbose message, nothing. They forgot to add messages for it.

Comment: I have set the loglevel in /etc/minidlna.conf on the server to "debug", to see what's happening when VLC is downloading the library; after half a minute VLC froze and the logging on the server also doesn't display anything since then ... VLC is useless for DLNA so far

Comment: I too have problems. I can't use the VLC that's in the repositories, nor can I use version 3 from snap. They both fail to even see my minidlna server. (I know the server is working because my Samsung T.V., both X-Boxes, both windows machines, and both android phones work fine with it.

Comment: VLC will fail to see upnp / dlna servers when you have more than one network interface including virtual bridge interfaces. Most recently, VLC fails on any new Macbook Pro which comes with more than one NIC interface.

Comment: Make this one 2023. I cannot fathom that VLC doesn't do this basic job. Have the developers not been informed? It is nothing but VLC that stands in the way. pulseaudio-dlna finds the renderer, W10 in any case, just a setting.
I would wish either a videolan-person to look into this; or - better - a *buntu solution similar to the overall setting in W10. 
(And, yes, I have tried that Playlist thingy in VLC. To no avail.)

Comment: VLC wasn't working on my machine because it used the wrong default network interface. Launching it with --miface=INTERFACE flag fixed it for me. The correct interface name can be found from `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 25):

First make sure that server is running fine. Then you can use djmount for upnp client. I don't know djmount is in the repo or not (I don't use ubuntu now). Install djmount & fuse.

make a mount point in /media

```
cd /media
sudo mkdir upnp
sudo chmod 777 upnp
```

You can give any name other than upnp

Then load fuse and mount the filesystem

```
sudo modprobe fuse
sudo djmount -o allow_other /media/upnp
```

You may have to restart the server. eg if you are running mediatomb

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mediatomb restart
```

Then browse to /media/upnp

However there is some problem. You have to remount it after every reboot.

Comment: Wow, great answer! Thanks. This is very useful. BTW, djmount is in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: djmount works fine without root access (no need to `sudo`). Just create a directory somewhere in your home folder and `djmount` on that (and also no need for `-o allow_other`).

Answer (score 18):

## [eezUPnP](http://www.eezupnp.de/index.html)

[image]

Java based application - download the zip file (32bit or 64bit) and run `./CP` in the extracted folder.

Obviously you need a [JAVA JRE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java) to be installed.

Be patient for the media servers to be recognised...

Comment: Only works for audio files. In my testing not really reliable.

Comment: Abandonware since 2017…

Answer (score 4):

After having tested now rythmbox, banshee (+rygel), xmbc, gstreamer/pulse  and a lot of other different upnp related software, i concluded that the only well working linux program is foobar with wine.

using it now on ubuntu 13.10 (with wine 1.6) and it works like a charm. all other linux based software did lack the "play to" feature known from media player or apple air.

however, the foobar ui is something you need to get used to. but now I really like it.

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem recently and created a [simple dlna browser](http://javier.io/blog/en/2016/01/22/simple-upnp-dlna-browser.html), I use it like this:

```
$ simple-dlna-browser -s 192.168.1.254 contacto | xargs mplayer
```

I took minidlna 1.1.4-2 as a reference, so it may not work with other media servers.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd
if [ ! -d upnp ]; then
mkdir upnp; chmod 777 upnp
sudo modprobe fuse
sudo djmount -o allow_other upnp/
xdg-open upnp
else
sudo fusermount -u upnp
rmdir upnp
echo umount upnp and rmdir
fi
```

but djmount crashed, in 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't work anymore, since this seemed to have broken in VLC 3+. `djmount` is also abandoned.

But you might not know (like me!) that **Totem** (the Gnome "Videos" player) will actually surf around upnp and can show videos from there. Go to "Channels" and you can click around.

If you want to listen to music, Rhythmbox has a DLNA-plugin.