# Can't see home media server on 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, server, windows-xp, mediaserver

Fair warning, Im a beginner at Ubuntu. I am running my home media server off of my old Windows desktop with Windows XP using Serviio and all the devices in my house can see it (XBOX, PS3, Smart TVs, my cell phone, Tablet, and my roommates windows computer) but I can't seem to find it on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.

When i go to Network > Windows Network and click on it it pops up and says

`unable to mount location. failed to receive shared list from server`
I'm sure someone out their knows how to fix this.

Comment: You will need a DLNA/UPnP client/renderer for this. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/88754/upnp-dlna-client-player-recommendations

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!