# What is the Yatse alternative for a PC?

Tags: xbmc

I have setup OpenElec on my raspberry pi and when I browse the files locally stored on my android device I can choose to `Play on Media Center` through the [Yatse app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree&hl=en). This way I can stream local files, I can stream youtube streams, I can stream anything that asks me what app I should use to play the media content. I just have to choose `play on media center` or `queue on media center`. When I do so, the movie starts on the raspberry pi almost immediately.

Now how would I do this on my (Ubuntu) laptop? How would I open movies directly on the openelec media center from my laptop? Preferably I would like to click `open with...` and then choose `openelec media center`.

Comment: @goldilocks Searching for `yatse` didn't give any results though.

Comment: VLC (and Popcorn Time, in some versions) have the ability to stream to XBMC. I have done that, but I no longer have a working XBMC system around to play with. Meanwhile, for VLC, here is a guide to get you started: http://kodi.wiki/view/Internet_video_and_audio_streams . Popcorn Time will find your XBMC automatically.

Comment: @goldilocks so are u saying i should install xbmc on my laptop too and let it stream the files between the xbmc installations?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://kodi.wiki/view/Web_interface  A blog tutorial about that here: [Use Chrome To Control Your XBMC Media Center](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/no-remote-no-problem-use-chrome-to-control-your-xbmc-media-center/)

Comment: @goldilocks I don't want to control the device remotely, I want to stream content from my laptop to the device, which isn't possible through the web interface

Comment: O_O And I went and deleted that link: http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Share_libraries_using_UPnP <- So you can share content between 2 `xbmc` instances on separate machines.

Comment: @goldilocks I ended up installing eezupnp as recommended [elsewhere on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/88815/258487). I'll close this answer as a duplicate as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPNP / DLNA (client) player recommendations?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88754/upnp-dlna-client-player-recommendations)