# Does anyone have a good suggestion for replacing djmount?

Tags: dlna, upnp

djmount is outdated, it seems like nobody is maintaining it, some of the bugs will never be fixed, is there any app can replace it?

Comment: otherwise http://askubuntu.com/questions/88754/upnp-dlna-client-player-recommendations has some suggestions.

Comment: Seeing that this was migrated from the SE site for Elementary OS,. please don't crosspost.

Comment: I love it that the "This question already exists" points to a dead link