# Stream music from phone or windows to local Ubuntu machine

Tags: networking, music, streaming

So I have found similar questions to this one, but I can't find one that's trying to achieve what I want. So my setup has a linux machine in a closet connected to an amplifier that's connected to my whole-office speakers. What I want to be able to do is stream music stored on my PC or in the form of Google Play Music on my phone to this linux box, and play it out of my speakers. Does anyone know what program I might look into to achieve this?

Also, it should be noted that my phone, PC, and the Linux machine are all on the same network.

Thanks!

Comment: See if any solution posted in this Q&A work for all your devices: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88754/upnp-dlna-client-player-recommendations