# Installing mods on Minecraft 1.0 does not work for Mo' Creatures

Tags: java, openjdk, minecraft

In attempting to get the Mo' Creatures mod working on Kubuntu 11.10 with OpenJRE-6 I get the following error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff855ec9c08, pid=4745, tid=140704592516864
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b23
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11pre
# Distribution: Ubuntu 11.10, package 6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x35c08]  XQueryExtension+0x28
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#
```

As per the report's suggestion, I was going to report the bug on launchpad, but figured I'd ask here first. There are others experiencing this as well: 
[Mo' Creatures for Minecraft refusing to work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11552858#post11552858)

Any ideas? Mojang recommends 64 bit Java, which is what I'm using. Thanks in advance.

Comment: report bug report at  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/

Answer (score 1):

I am a minecraft player and have used many mods, but not Mo Creatures. Do you have any other mods set up that may be causing a conflict?

Comment: No this is the only mod. I have used other mods in the past and know how to install them without issue. Also, Mo' Creatures requires Modloader to run which I can install just fine. This mod appears to work in other Linux distributions, as well as Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04 as far as I can tell from Googling the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Submit bug report on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/) 
alternatively you can use sun/oracle java 
see this questions

1. [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7)
2. [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)