# How can I install OpenJDK 7 on 10.04 LTS?

Tags: 10.04, java, openjdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I noticed it's available on 11.10, but is there a backport to lucid 10.04 LTS?