# What happens when there are 2 versions of a terminal command installed?

Tags: command-line, java, versions

For example, I have OpenJDK 6 and 7 both installed. If I run 
    javac foo.java
will is compile my program as a Java 6 program or a Java 7 program?

Comment: Multiple duplicates, i.e.: [install jre-7](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7) [how to install java](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian-based distributions have so-called "alternatives" system, which allows to have more than one program installed which perform the same function (this also includes different versions of the same program, like Java 6 and Java 7). As @user15936 points out, the system works by manipulating symlinks, so "javac" can point to the executable either from OpenJDK 6 or from OpenJDK 7

The command to manipulate the above mentioned symlinks (the process is in fact more complex than that as it includes some configuration, for example manpages change too etc.) - is called `update-alternatives`. You can learn how to use it by typing `man update-alternatives` in terminal.

To directly answer your question, another way to determine which javac executable will be invoked is by doing

```
update-alternatives --display javac
```

Comment: There is even the specialized `update-java-alternatives`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is whichever is linked to `/usr/bin/javac`

That will be executed.

You can see this by going to `/usr/bin/` and see the link javac is connected by doing `ls -l javac`.

Answer (score -1):

You should type in a terminal `javac -version` and there you will get your answer...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer, particularly for users where Oracle Java (JVM/JDK) is no longer provided as a .deb & they manually installed. Highly recommended reading, especially about the 'update java' script' which will set the various alternatives - http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html

Comment: I didn't vote down, but java and javac might belong to different versions.